# How to groupBy array of objects based on properties in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

How do you **groupBy** array of objects based on specific properties in vanilla javascript? For example this given:

```
const products = [
  {
    category: "Sporting Goods",
    price: "$49.99",
    stocked: true,
    name: "Football"
  },
  {
    category: "Sporting Goods",
    price: "$9.99",
    stocked: true,
    name: "Baseball"
  },
  {
    category: "Sporting Goods",
    price: "$29.99",
    stocked: false,
    name: "Basketball"
  },
  {
    category: "Electronics",
    price: "$99.99",
    stocked: true,
    name: "iPod Touch"
  },
  {
    category: "Electronics",
    price: "$399.99",
    stocked: false,
    name: "iPhone 5"
  },
  { category: "Electronics", price: "$199.99", stocked: true, name: "Nexus 7" }
];
```

i want to run a reduce function that would result to a new array of objects like this:

**Intended Output:**

```
const categorize = [
  {
    category:"Sporting Goods",
    products: [
      {
        name:"Football",
        price: "$49.99",
        stocked: true
      },
      {
        name:"Baseball",
        price: "$9.99",
        stocked: true
      },
      {
        name:"Basketball",
        price: "$29.99",
        stocked: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    category: "Electronics",
    products: [
      {
        name: "iPod Touch",
        price: "$99.99",
        stocked: true
      },
      {
        name: "iPhone 5",
        price: "$399.99",
        stocked: false
      },
      {
        name: "Nexus 7",
        price: "$199.99",
        stocked: true
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i based my solution from the tutorial here: https://www.consolelog.io/group-by-in-javascript/  using the reduce function.

**Here's my code:**

```
const groupBy = (arr,prop)=>{
  return arr.reduce((groups,item)=>{
    let val = item[prop];
    groups[val] = groups[val]||[];
    groups[val].push(item);
    return groups
  },{});
}

const categorize = groupBy(products,'category');
console.log(categorize);

/* returns an Object like
    Object {Sporting Goods: Array[3], Electronics: Array[3]}
   however it's not the intended output.
*/
```

I tried to return `Object.values(obj)` or `Object.entries(obj)` inside the groupBy function but it just returns an array of 2 arrays like `[Array[3],Array[3]]` and if i set the initial value (2nd parameter of reduce) to empty [] instead of {}, the output is just an empty array. Need help, thanks!

Comment: Are you ok to use any third party library like underscore.js ?

Comment: this may be the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Comment: @Sohan i want it to be vanilla as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you want an array containing *objects* (rather than just an array of plain values), create a `{ category, products: [] }` object if it doesn't exist in the accumulator:

```js
const products=[{category:"Sporting Goods",price:"$49.99",stocked:!0,name:"Football"},{category:"Sporting Goods",price:"$9.99",stocked:!0,name:"Baseball"},{category:"Sporting Goods",price:"$29.99",stocked:!1,name:"Basketball"},{category:"Electronics",price:"$99.99",stocked:!0,name:"iPod Touch"},{category:"Electronics",price:"$399.99",stocked:!1,name:"iPhone 5"},{category:"Electronics",price:"$199.99",stocked:!0,name:"Nexus 7"}];

const output = Object.values(
  products.reduce((a, { category, ...item }) => {
    if (!a[category]) {
      a[category] = { category, products: [] };
    }
    a[category].products.push(item);
    return a;
  }, {})
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks much! Please can you explain your answer in a little more understandable for beginners. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function (){
var map = {};
products.forEach((p) => {
  if (map[p.category]) {
 var c = p.category;
delete p.category;
  map[c].push(p);
} else {
 var c = p.category;
delete p.category;
map[c]=[c]
}
});

Object.keys(map).forEach((m) => {
ans.push({category:m, products: map[m]})
})
```

}

you can collect in one go products and map them.
Then make your resultinng array